# NEHE Lesson 06 broken in LWJGL, what should i use instead of org.lwjgl.devil.IL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

In the NEHE Lesson 06 (http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) It has you load an image and texture an object with it.
I am currently using LWJGL, and the version i am using right now does not have the org.lwjgl.devil.IL that the LWJGL version of the tutorial has.

Now i am stuck on lesson 6, would anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Devil texture library is no longer part of LWJGL since version 2.x. Some alternatives that you can use are libraries like Slick-Util or PNGDecoder. Tutorials for these can be found on the [LWJGL Wiki](http://wiki.lwjgl.org) under the Helper Library section.

Comment: Well poop, this is gonna test my understanding of java! Thanks!